# Opencv Matrix Range L value : Is this a bug?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, range, assignment-operator

It seems to me that using Matrix with Ranges as an L-value (assignment target) should work or not (and if not a compiler error would be nice) but not both depending on the particulars of a legitimate r-value.

```
cout << "hi mom" <<  endl;
Mat Img0=Mat::zeros(7,7,CV_8UC1);
Mat Img1=Mat::ones(7,7,CV_8UC1);
cout << Img0 << endl;
cout << Img1 << endl;
Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1;
cout << Img0 << endl;
Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = 1;
cout << Img0 << endl;
```

Below is the output from the above.  The first two matrix print outs are of `Img0` and `Img1` as initialized by `Mat::zeros` and `Mat::ones` respectively.

The third matrix print out is `Img0` again but after

**`Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1;`**

which I expected would set `Img0` to `Img1`; i.e. all ones; **but it's not.  It's still all zeros.**

The fourth/last matrix print out is the result of

**`Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = 1;`**

Which has the same L value as the third assignment but it works when a scalar is the Rvalue (unlike the third which as a matrix as the RValue).

Is there some sense in this that I'm missing?  Should this r-value distinction behavior be allowed?  It seems inconsistent to me.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not a bug.**

This line `Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1;` doesn't work as expected because `Img0(Range::all(), Range::all())` **forms a temporary header that is further assigned to another header, which is `Img1`. Remember that each of these operations is O(1), that is, no data is copied.** Thus, no real assignment happens.

You can realize this effect more clearly by doing this:

```
(Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1) = 2;
cout << Img0 << endl;
cout << Img1 << endl;
```

If you have understood what I described above, you should be aware of that the code will only change the value of `Img1`. And the output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

**Further reading:** check out similar effect happened to [**`Mat::row()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-row).

Comment: 1) This still makes the basic effect on the lvalue completely  r-value dependent. 2) What;'s the point of this syntax?  What possible benefit is there to Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1; given what it actually does?    As I understand you, Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()) = Img1 is the same as img1=Img0(Range::all(), Range::all()).  Img1 becomes a header into Img0.